# Why is a compiled java bytecode file called a class file?

Tags: java

I started off learning java for object oriented programming , then I started learning C#, ASP.NET MVC. Now I am revisiting Java again just for fun.

In C#, source files have the .cs extension and CIL code has the .exe extension. This makes sense to me.  An "exe" extension is intuitive to me if I want to execute it that file.

So java has the .java extension for source code, but why is the extension for java bytecode called .class ?

Comment: That's the name the author of Java decide for it. Maybe you should email James Gosling and ask him about this decision.

Comment: Naming it .exe wouldn't be smart considering java isn't made for Windows.

Comment: Perhaps because a .java file can contain multiple classes, but the compiler generates exactly one .class file for each class?

Comment: `.exe`s can run indepenantly, `class` files requires a virtial machine to run on (even if its in a runnable .jar). And as mentioned a .class (or .jar) can run on any system with a JVM, not just windows

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because it removed the actual question.

Comment: I think you need to understand what is meant by `.java` and `.class`. This will solve your question.

Check this site:
[what is the difference between a java and class files?]
 (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_a_java_and_class_files#slide=3)

Comment: I'm not saying using .class was a mistake, I'm just curious to know if anyone else knew about the historical reason about why the name was chosen. Even the programming name "Java" had some fun meaning behind it.

Comment: @Salman. Thanks, but I already knew that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is `.class` because that is what the designers of Java decided on.

And it is pretty intuitive: a `.class` file contains the bytecode of a single class. So a single source `.java` file may result in multiple `.class` files, even anonymous classes get their own `.class` files.

See [The class File Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) in the JVM specification.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the link to the JVM spec.